# Element ref was specified as a string (map) but no owner was set

Tags: reactjs

I have updated my project to React 16.3.1 and now I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Element ref was specified as a string (map) but no owner was set. You may have multiple copies of React loaded. (details: https://fb(dot)me/react-refs-must-have-owner).
    at invariant (invariant.js:42)
    at coerceRef (react-dom.development.js:6736)
    at createChild (react-dom.development.js:6977)
    at reconcileChildrenArray (react-dom.development.js:7282)
    at reconcileChildFibers (react-dom.development.js:7651)
    at reconcileChildrenAtExpirationTime (react-dom.development.js:7756)
    at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js:7747)
    at updateHostComponent (react-dom.development.js:7998)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:8229)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:10224)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:10288)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:542)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:581)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:438)
    at renderRoot (react-dom.development.js:10366)
    at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:11014)
    at performWork (react-dom.development.js:10967)
    at requestWork (react-dom.development.js:10878)
    at scheduleWorkImpl (react-dom.development.js:10732)
    at scheduleWork (react-dom.development.js:10689)
    at Object.enqueueSetState (react-dom.development.js:6212)
    at Wrapper.../node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js.Component.setState (react.development.js:242)
    at Wrapper.onLoad (GoogleApiComponent.js:194)
    at ScriptCache.js:39
```

I'm a total newbie so I'm not sure what exactly I should look for to spot the error.

PS. I have excluded the multiple copies option as when I run `npm ls react` I get:

```
└── react@16.3.1
```

Comment: Have you checked the following change on the ```ref```(```createRef();```) in the ```16.3.1```:

https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/29/react-v-16-3.html

Comment: given the error, which string should I look for?

Comment: Can you please put the related code here?

Comment: unfortunately I'm not authorised. What would you look for?

Comment: make sure you updated `react-dom` as well, and maybe try to remove node_modules and run `npm install`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to react documentation on version 16.3 changes, the legacy string ref api is deprecated and now you should use the ref callback api as follows

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.inputRef = React.createRef();
  }

  render() {
    return <input type="text" ref={this.inputRef} />;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.inputRef.current.focus();
  }
}
```